# How can I get the Delphi IDE's Main Form?

Tags: delphi, ide

I'm writing a property editor for Delphi and I would like it to show up on the correct screen for multi-monitor support. In order to position it, I would like a reference to the "main" form for the Delphi IDE.

I've tried using the Application's MainForm property, and the Application object itself, but neither seems to work. I believe this is because the MainForm is actually the hidden TApplication instance referenced in this article by Nathanial Woolls (search for "application form"):

http://www.installationexcellence.com/articles/VistaWithDelphi/Original/Index.html

Does anyone know how to get a handle to the visible main form for the IDE. I'm trying to avoid something cheesy like iterating all forms and searching for "CodeGear RAD Studio" in the caption.

Comment: I'd expect a property editor to appear on the same screen as the Object Inspector or as the Form Designer, depending on which one I used to invoke the property editor. Who cares about the application form?

Comment: I agree, but I had no idea how to get the handle of the object inspector window, so I started with an easier task that would likely be correct for the majority of users. I've also considered just getting the mouse position, then monitor it is currently in, and using that.

Comment: @Jeremy Mullin: Can you share your findings please ?

Comment: My findings are in the comments on the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IDE's main form is Application.MainForm. My quick test design package:

```
procedure DoStuff(Form: TCustomForm);
var
  S: string;
begin
  S := Form.Caption;
  Form.Caption := S + ' - this one';
  try
    ShowMessage(Format('%s [%s] on monitor %d', [Form.Name, Form.ClassName, Form.Monitor.MonitorNum]));
  finally
    Form.Caption := S;
  end;
end;

initialization
  DoStuff(Application.MainForm);
```

This in my case displays "AppBuilder [TAppBuilder] on monitor 0" and I can see the " - this one" suffix in the main form's caption.
What doesn't seem to work in your case?

Comment: I'm assigning it as an owner of a form, then trying to use Form.Position to correctly position the form to poOwnerCenter. When I get in to work I'll verify I'm getting the correct form and check the Form.Monitor property like you did. Thanks!

Comment: I got it working, it was a scope issue. I was referencing Application.MainForm not in my design time BPL, but in a DLL that it had loaded. In that scope it was returning nil. I couldn't use the TForm.Position property on forms created inside the DLL (I'm assuming for the same scoping reason), but I was able to use the Application.MainForm.Monitor position and dimensions retrieved while in the BPL to manually position the form. Thanks for the push in the right direction!

Answer (score 2):

IIRC the main form is called `TAppBuilder`, so something like `FindWindow('TAppBuilder',nil)` might be a starting point for you.